# ember data reload() undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to reload a model that has changed on the server.  My code is as follows:

```
App.CustomersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  intervalId: undefined,
  startRefreshing: function() {
    var self = this;
    if ( self.get( 'intervalId' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    self.set( 'intervalId', setInterval( function() {
        //self.get('model').update();
        self.get('model').reload();
    }, 30000 ) );
  }
});

App.CustomersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('customer');
  },
  setupController: function( controller, model ){
    this._super( controller, model );
    controller.startRefreshing();
  },

  actions: {
    reload: function() {
        this.get('model' ).reload();
    }
  }
});
```

You can see that I have two mechanisms for reloading the data - one a timer, and also an action triggered by a button in the UI.  The latter is exactly what is shown in the ember-data documentation here: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload

Neither works.  I get undefined in both cases i.e. the model returned does not have a reload() method.  update() sort of works, except it does not remove deleted records and it is not what is recommended in the documentation.  What am I doing wrong here in trying to use reload?

My stack:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.1+pre.07fafb84
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7.f87cba88 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.0 
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

and I am using the following adapter in case that makes any difference:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  // Override the default adapter with the `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` which
  // is built to work nicely with the ActiveModel::Serializers gem.
    adapter: '-active-model'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`reload` exists on a record, not a collection.

You would need to iterate the collection and call reload on each record.

```
self.get('model').forEach(function(record){
  record.reload();
});
```

But I'm guessing you don't want to waste the callbacks to the server.  In this case I'd recommend returning a filter as your model, then make another call to the server for all records.

```
App.CustomersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.store.find('customer');
    return this.store.all('customer');
  },
  setupController: function( controller, model ){
    this._super( controller, model );
    controller.startRefreshing();
  },

  actions: {
    reload: function() {
        this.get('model' ).reload();
    }
  }
});

App.CustomersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  intervalId: undefined,
  startRefreshing: function() {
    var self = this;
    if ( self.get( 'intervalId' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    self.set( 'intervalId', setInterval( function() {
        self.store.find('customer');  // get all customers again, updating the ones we have
    }, 30000 ) );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. So self.store.find('customer') does make a call to the backend similar to update().  However, it does not remove records that are no longer in the backend model.  So if I add a record I see my record count increase by 1 and I see it locally.  If I delete a record, my backend has 1 less record then my ember model does.  Only way I have found around this is to call this.store.unloadAll and then to load all the records again.  Unfortunately that causes a nasty flashing as all my records are removed and re-added and all the views update in between the two calls.

Comment: I really wish there was just a way to re-sync the ember model with the backend model.

Comment: I've been working with https://github.com/kurko/ember-sync and the indexedDB plugin. It's still a WIP, but definitely worth checking out as it is moving in the right direction.